# How to use datetime type in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, format

I am attempting to create a table with SQL, where one of my columns must be of the type "datetime", however, I wish to use my local time format, which is:
DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM:SS

```
CREATE TABLE Topics
(
    TopicID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    TopicTitle Nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    TopicDate datetime NOT NULL,
    TopicText Nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    UserID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserID)
)
```

How do I make the `DATETIME` type input be of the format I specified above?

Thank you!

John

Comment: Just curious... who uses `DD:MM:YYYY` ? I'm familiar with `dmy`, but not the colons as delimiters.

Comment: Datetime is a datetime is a datetime datatype. Format when selecting the data for display, not storing your data.

Comment: We do that in Denmark, and most European countries, I think :-)

Comment: Ah, okay.. so I do not have to worry about the specifics in SQL, but only when inputting and selecting the data?

Comment: @JohnTheHun Not in France we don't :)

Comment: @JohnTheHun Neat. I thought you used `.` to delimit `dmy` there.

Comment: You will have to handle the format while reading from the table. There is no possibility to STORE in a certain format

Comment: Well, we might do DMY, but the colons are only used for the time portion: e.g. `2.11.2017 18:04:12`

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a language setting that will correctly parse datetime literals that use a colon as a delimiter between `dd:mm:yyyy`, but you can swap the first two colons for periods using `stuff()`, and use `format()` (Sql Server 2012+) for output:

```
/* adjusting input to a string that can convert to datetime */
declare @s varchar(20) = '02:11:2017 16:59:16';
select dt = convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(@s,3,1,'.'),6,1,'.'),103)

/* return datetime using specified format */
select dt = format(getdate(),'dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```